# Generate splash

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to generate splash before my tabbar based application starts. Please help me out....

Comment: Have you tried using a launch image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: Create your splash image and name it Default.png.

A tutorial can be found [here](http://gigaom.com/apple/iphone-dev-sessions-making-a-splash-screen/).

Comment: Your answer was really helpful. But, I want to add some animations and when a click is performed on the screen I want to display some event.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable guidance

Comment: @Milesh you should edit your question to reflect this additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an animated splash screen on iOS.
You MUST start by an image.

However what you can do is

1. Setup a launch image
2. display a view controller that animate then move on to your application

One common practice is to setup a launch image that is the first image of your animation.
this way the user won't see the difference between the static and animated parts of your splash screen.